# gost-crypto hash algorithm in php5.6

Tags: php, hash, php-5.6, gost3411

In alpha release of php5.6 a new hash algorithm [gost-crypto](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.gost) was added. I tried to look into documentation but the only information I found that it is added and nothing else.

Also there is no information on google (due to the fact that it was released today).

So how should I use it (`gost-crypto('hello');` does not work) and in what cases is is better then other already available hashes [md5](https://www.php.net/md5) or [crypt](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)?

Comment: Does it show up in [`hash_algos()`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-algos.php)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see the new tests here: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/hash/tests/gost.phpt?source=c

> ```
> echo hash('gost-crypto', 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'), "\n";
> ```

The relevant ticket with more explanations is here: https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/430

> This adds a new hash identifier "gost-crypto" which uses the CryptoPro
>   S-box tables as specified by RFC 4357, section 11.2.
>
> GOST algorithm with CryptoPro S-Box generates different set of hash
>   values. CryptoPro S-box is required among other for DNSSEC GOST
>   signatures (RFC 5933).
>
> See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GOST_(hash_function)

Answer (score -3):

It's a hash algorithm, I guess you can use it now instead of say, `CRYPT_BLOWFISH` in functions that support it (like `crypt()`).

Comment: Thanks, but this does not look like an answer. This is more appropriate for a comment if you are just guessing.